# How to Decode in Lower Resolution Through Media Codec in Android . Like I want to decode 1920*1080 resolution video in 1280*720 output

Tags: android, media, android-mediacodec

How to Decode in Lower Resolution Through Media Codec in Android . Like I want to decode 1920*1080 resolution video in 1280*720 output format throught media code. I have tried KEY_MAX_WIDTH and KEY_MAX_HEIGHT but it alwas decode in original resolution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.